# Angle of projection of Projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Is there an angle of projection for which both height attained by projectile and range become simultaneously maximum?

Answer (score 1):

No. Height is maximum when the projectile is launched straight up ($90^{\circ}$ to the horizontal). Range is maximum when the launch angle is $45^{\circ}$ to the horizontal. They do not reach a maximum simultaneously.

Comment: Despite what some dictionaries would tell you, the plural of *maximum* is *maxima*. Words borrowed from Latin are funny like that.